# Azure Blob Storage File size exceeds max supported file size using ionic 3 app

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal

I am able to upload images from my ionic 3 mobile app to my azure blob storage.
only issue is if i upload a large image say 3-4 Mb size it gets uploaded
but when i try to download and open from azure blob storage it give me this error ***File size of 4.08 MB exceeds max supported file size of 2.05 MB.***
So my query is how do i increase the size up to 5 Mb of the blob storage so that i can upload large size images.
[image]
when i click edit button i get error

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you downloading the blobs?

Comment: downloading in azure blob storage

Comment: I doubt if the error is coming from Azure Storage. A blob can be much-much larger in size. Can you edit your question and include the complete error?

Comment: There is a limitation of editing file in Azure portal. You can just edit a file in portal which size is under 2.05MB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**There is a limit of editing file in Azure portal**. You can just edit a file in portal which size is under 2.05MB.  I think this feature is designed for editing some little size file such as `txt`. For pictures, portal just opens it, you cannot edit it indeed.

This limit is only for editing file in Azure portal, **not for uploading file size**. So, you still can upload big size file to Azure Blob. For more details about Azure Storage limits, you can refer to [**this document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits).

Additional, this limits cannot be changed by users because it's designed. If you still want to expand the size of editing file  in Azure portal which uploaded into a blob, you can post your idea in [this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage),the Azure Team will see it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One of the option to easy edit and upload is [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/#overview), you can download file using it, edit via external editor (in my case it was Visual Studio Code) and upload to the Azure. It also detects changes and propose making snapshot of original file which is cool:

[image]